# How to use summarise?

Tags: r

Here is the dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(number = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3), 
                 heahache = c(1,1,na,na,na,1,na),
                 pain = c(na,1,1,na,1,na,na),
                 futigue = c(na,na,1,na,1,1,1))

   headache  pain futigue
1     1       na     na
1     1       1      na
2     na      1      1
2     na      na     na
2     na      1      1
3     1       na     1
3     na      na     1
```

The first result that I want is to get how many times each symptom appeared like this

```
   headache  pain futigue
1     2       1     0
2     0       2     2
3     1       0     2
```

The second result is to calculate how many symptoms each person got like

```
     symptoms
1      2
2      2
3      2
```

Since the real data set has 50+ columns discribing different symptoms, any idea to manage large data set? Thank you.

Comment: First, [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) your data.  Then the number of columns becomes irrelevant and your code becomes shorter and more robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just use `summarise` from `dplyr` and doesn't need any additional packages. For larger dataset, reshaping could be costly.  Would recommend to `summarise` first and use `rowSums` (vectorized and efficient) to create the 'Symptoms' column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(number) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(!is.na(.))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  number headache  pain fatigue
*  <dbl>    <int> <int>   <int>
1      1        2     1       0
2      2        0     2       2
3      3        1     0       2
```

---

If we need the `symptoms` column

```
df %>%
    group_by(number) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(!is.na(.)))) %>%
    mutate(Symptoms = rowSums(.[-1] > 0))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  number headache  pain fatigue Symptoms
#*  <dbl>    <int> <int>   <int>    <dbl>
#1      1        2     1       0        2
#2      2        0     2       2        2
#3      3        1     0       2        2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(number = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), headache = c(1, 
1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA), pain = c(NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA), fatigue = c(NA, 
NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Could you please explain what does (.[-1] > 0) mean?

Comment: @CouchTomato The first column is `number` with `.[-1]` we are excluding the first column from the `rowSums`

Answer (score 2):

First, tidy your data (note the corrections of typos: na should be NA, heahache should be headache and futigue should be fatigue):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(number = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3), 
                 headache = c(1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA),
                 pain = c(NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,NA),
                 fatigue = c(NA,NA,1,NA,1,1,1))
longDF <- df %>% 
            pivot_longer(
              cols=c(headache, pain, fatigue),
              names_to="Symptom",
              values_to="Present"
            ) %>% 
            replace_na(list(Present=0))
```

Then to count appearances:

```
longDF %>% 
  group_by(number, Symptom) %>% 
  summarise(Count=sum(Present)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from=Symptom,
    values_from=Count
  )
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   number [3]
  number fatigue headache  pain
   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1      1       0        2     1
2      2       2        0     2
3      3       2        1     0
```

and the number of symptoms experienced by each `number`:

```
longDF %>% 
  filter(Present == 1) %>% 
  group_by(number) %>% 
  summarise(symptoms=length(unique(Symptom)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  number symptoms
*  <dbl>    <int>
1      1        2
2      2        2
3      3        2
```

Note that this final calculation will omit `number`s who do not experience any symptoms.  To do that, a little more work will be required.  To show the problem, add a `number` who exprienced no symptoms:

```
newDF <- longDF %>% 
           add_row(number=4, Symptom="headache", Present=0) %>% 
           add_row(number=4, Symptom="fatigue", Present=0) %>% 
           add_row(number=4, Symptom="pain", Present=0)
```

Demonstrate the problem:

```
newDF %>% 
  filter(Present == 1) %>% 
  group_by(number) %>% 
  summarise(symptoms=length(unique(Symptom)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  number symptoms
*  <dbl>    <int>
1      1        2
2      2        2
3      3        2
```

And solve it:

```
newDF %>% 
  filter(Present == 1) %>% 
  group_by(number) %>% 
  summarise(symptoms=length(unique(Symptom))) %>% 
  right_join(newDF %>% distinct(number), by="number") %>% 
  replace_na(list(symptoms=0))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  number symptoms
   <dbl>    <dbl>
1      1        2
2      2        2
3      3        2
4      4        0
```